# Optimizing string search in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have to write a python program that given a large 50 MB DNA sequence and a smaller one, of around 15 characters, returns a list of all sequences of 15 characters ordered by how close they are to the one given as well as where they are in the larger one.

My current approach is to first get all the subsequences:

```
def get_subsequences_of_size(size, data):
    sequences = {}
    i = 0
    while(i+size <= len(data)):
        sequence = data[i:i+size]
        if sequence not in sequences:
            sequences[sequence] = data.count(sequence)
        i += 1
    return sequences
```

and then pack them in a list of dictionaries according to what the problem asked (I forgot to get the position):

```
def find_similar_sequences(seq, data):
    similar_sequences = {}
    sequences = get_subsequences_of_size(len(seq), data)
    for sequence in sequences.keys():
        diffs, muts = calculate_similarity(seq,sequence)
        if diffs not in similar_sequences:
            similar_sequences[diffs] = [{"Sequence": sequence, "Mutations": muts}]
        else:
            similar_sequences[diffs].append({"Sequence": sequence, "Mutations": muts})
        #similar_sequences[sequence] = {"Similarity": (len(sequence)-diffs), "Differences": diffs, "Mutatations": muts}
    return similar_sequences
```

My problem is that this running way too slow. With the 50MB input, it takes over 30 minutes to finish processing.

Comment: Could you please explain what is your problem?

Comment: Man, I had to edit it so many times I must have forgotten it. Sorry!
I've edited the post to add it, but the problem is that it runs way too slow for me.
With the 50MB input it takes over 30mins to run.

Comment: Perhaps try rephrasing your scientific question, instead of looking for all 15 k-mers, try looking for the perfect hit, one mutation, two mutations, etc. Alternatively have a look at this library: http://khmer.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1-0/ktable.html

Comment: Try here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What about the following approach:

Go with a sliding window of length 15 over your long sequence and for every subsequence:

- store the start location on the long sequence
- calculate and store the similarity

```
import re
from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict

short_seq = 'TGGCGACGGACTTCA'
long_seq = 'AGAACGTTTCGCGTCAGCCCGGAAGTGGTCAGTCGCCTGAGTCCGAACAAAAATGACAACAACGTTTATGACAGAACATT' +\
           'CCTTGCTGGCAACTACCTGAAAATCGGCTGGCCGTCAGTCAATATCATGTCCTCATCAGATTATAAATGCGTGGCGCTGA' +\
           'CGGATTATGACCGTTTTCCGGAAGATATTGATGGCGAGGGGGATGCCTTCTCTCTTGCCTCAAAACGTACCACCACATTT' +\
           'ATGTCCAGTGGTATGACGCTGGTGGAGAGTTCCCCCGGCAGGGATGTGAAGGATGTGAAATGGCGACGGACTTCACCGCA' +\
           'TGAGGCTCCACCAACCACGGGGATACTGTCGCTCTATAACCGTGGCGATCGCCGTCGCTGGTACTGGCCCTGTCCACACT' +\
           'GTGGTGAGTATTTTCAGCCCTGCGGCGATGTGGTTGCTGGTTTCCGTGATATTGCCGATCCCGTGCTGGCAAGTGAGGCG' +\
           'GCTTATATTCAGTGTCCTTCTGGCGACGGACTTCACGCGTCAGCCCGGAAGTGGTCAGTCGCCTGAGTCCGAACAAAAAT'


def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    # from https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield ''.join(result)
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield ''.join(result)

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

k = len(short_seq)
locations = defaultdict(list)
similarities = defaultdict(set)

for start, subseq in enumerate(window(long_seq, k)):
    locations[subseq].append(start)
    similarity = hamming_distance(subseq, short_seq) # substitute with your own similarity function
    similarities[similarity].add(subseq)

with open(r'stack46268997.txt', 'w') as f:
    for similarity in sorted(similarities.keys()):
        f.write("Sequence(s) which differ in {} base(s) from the short sequence:\n".format(similarity))
        for subseq in similarities[similarity]:
            f.write("{} at location(s) {}\n".format(subseq, ', '.join(map(str, locations[subseq]))))
        f.write('\n')
```

This outputs the list of subsequences ordered by how close they are to the given sequence.

```
Sequence(s) which differ in 0 base(s) from the short sequence:
TGGCGACGGACTTCA at location(s) 300, 500

Sequence(s) which differ in 5 base(s) from the short sequence:
TGGCGATCGCCGTCG at location(s) 362

Sequence(s) which differ in 6 base(s) from the short sequence:
TGGCAACTACCTGAA at location(s) 86
TGGTGAGTATTTTCA at location(s) 401
TGGCGAGGGGGATGC at location(s) 191

Sequence(s) which differ in 7 base(s) from the short sequence:
ATGTGAAGGATGTGA at location(s) 283
AGGGGGATGCCTTCT at location(s) 196
TGACAACAACGTTTA at location(s) 53
CGCTGACGGATTATG at location(s) 154
TTATGACCGTTTTCC at location(s) 164
TGGTTGCTGGTTTCC at location(s) 430
TCGCGTCAGCCCGGA at location(s) 8
AGTCGCCTGAGTCCG at location(s) 30, 536
CGGCGATGTGGTTGC at location(s) 422

[... and so on...]
```

I also ran the script on a 50 MB FASTA file. On my machine, this took 42 seconds to compute the results and another 30 seconds to write out the results to a file (printing them out would have taken much longer!)